# Autoreload vimrc when writing to vimscript files

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I wanted to have my vimrc automatically update when I write to a .vim file using this autocmd:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.vim,$MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
```

But for some reason when I have this enabled and then do `:w` in my vimrc, my vimrc is pasted into my current buffer at the cursor position. How can I prevent this, and why does `source` behave like this?

Comment: If you do `:source $MYVIMRC` manually, does this happen? If so, its probably a bug in your vimrc

Comment: No, it did not happen if I sourced manually.. I don't exactly know what does it but with this code it works:
```augroup reload_vimrc |
  autocmd! |
  autocmd BufWritePost *.vim,vimrc,$MYVIMRC ++once source $MYVIMRC | e |
augroup END
```

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer. I can explain what it does, but the original issue may be a quirk of your vimrc. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: It would still be nice to understand why the original autocmd wasn't working... Anything specific in your vimrc that was causing that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
augroup reload_vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost *.vim,vimrc,$MYVIMRC ++once source $MYVIMRC | e
augroup END
```

It

1. does the `augroup group`/`autocmd!` dance to set up a group and clear any commands already in it
2. establishes a one-time (`++once`) autocmd that

   1. sources the vimrc
   2. uses `:edit` to re-edit the current file (effectively sourcing its ftplugins and such again)
3. Ends the group

Comment: OP, I've edited to explain the code. If you feel that is inappropriate, rollback and ping me and I'll add my own answer.

Comment: Well, thank you.