# To reload vimrc on file save

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to make Vim reload its vimrc when I save a file. I have found different solutions, but none of them works for me for some reason.

Vim version: 8.2.2824, OS: Windows 7.

My vimrc:

```
" I start Vim, type foo, save a buffer as test.txt,
" change colorcolumn to 20, type bar in test.txt, and save it again.
" The colorcolumn doesn't move.
set colorcolumn=5

" version 1
" autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC execute "normal! :source $MYVIMRC"

" version 2
" autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC

" version 3
" autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source %

" version 4
" augroup reload_vimrc
"  autocmd!
"  autocmd BufWritePost *.vim,vimrc,$MYVIMRC ++once source $MYVIMRC | e
" augroup END

" There is nothing else.
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
augroup reload_vimrc | au!
    au BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
augroup END
```

> " version 1
> " autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC execute "normal! :source $MYVIMRC"

This is a bit awkward way to `source $MYVIMRC`

> " version 2
> " autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC

This should work (and actually works for me).

> " version 3
> " autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source %

This should also work (and works for me)

> " version 4
> " augroup reload_vimrc
> "  autocmd!
> "  autocmd BufWritePost *.vim,vimrc,$MYVIMRC ++once source $MYVIMRC | e
> " augroup END

This should not work properly (it will source once your vimrc if you save any `.vim` file or your `vimrc`).

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Strange. Version 4 is from here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21848

Comment: if you do `:source $MYVIMRC` would it reload it?

Comment: Hey, if I edit `_vimrc` with the same instance of Vim (and not with external editor, Sublime Text), it works. It seems I just messed the whole workflow. So now I accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `$MYVIMRC` to be sourced after saving *any* file?

If so, then you would need to change the filter argument in your autocmd:

```
autocmd! BufWritePost * source $MYVIMRC
```

Any filename matching the `*` pattern will trigger this autocmd.

Comment: No, it's not my intent, but thanks for the explanation regarding asterisk. The downvotes are not from me.

Comment: Haha, I was surprised that none of your original attempts worked, so I figured I give an answer.